# AutoHotKey AHK Is there a way to move the mouse based on screen image

Tags: autohotkey

In a browser a link always changes.

With AHK, is there a way to search an image pattern (like our eyes) and click at the found location?

Comment: Thanks, Blackholyman! 

It works great except one thing. 

A browser does not always display a text in exactly the same - sometimes one pixel wider.  Is there is a way to roughly, not exactly compare the two images? I tried *n and *transxxxx, seems not help.

Answer (score 0):

One word ["Imagesearch"](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm)

With it you can search all or a region of the visible screen for an image